# Program in Prolog for sum of numbers in interval

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a program in Prolog which takes two numbers - A and B and finds the sum of the numbers from A to B, including them.

To sum up: sum(1, 5, C) should find that C is 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

This is my code, which is not working :(

```
sum(A, B, C) :- A =< B, A1 is A+1, C1 is C+A, sum(A1, B, C1).
```

And then I test it with `sum(1, 5, C).`

What I get is `ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`, but I can't really get what is the problem. :(

Could you please help me to understand why it's not working and how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't instantiate `C1` as `C+A` because `C` is not yet an integer.

Let's call `sum(1, 5, C)`

```
sum(1, 5, C)

---> 1 =< 5 ... true

---> A1 is 1 + 1 ... A1 = 2 (fine)

---> C1 is C + 2, C = something like _G232, not yet instantiated.
```

Let's take a look at your logic.

We would have a base case,  when A and B are equal, that will be our 'starting' sum

```
sum(X,X,X).
```

Then we have our general case. each recursive call will give us the sum from k + 1 to n where we call sum(k,n,sum).

```
sum(A, B, C):- A =< B, A1 is A + 1, sum(A1,B,C1), C is C1 + A.
```

Answer (score 4):

Available in SWI-Prolog, library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) is a full fledged interface:

```
?- aggregate(sum(N), between(1,5,N), S).
S = 15.
```

it does internally a similar work as you can read in Kaarel' answer. Anyway, to learn Prolog, follow C.B. detailed explanation.

Comment: Cleanest way to solve it. With `findall`, `library(apply)`, and `library(aggreggate)` there are trivial, obvious solutions to many problems.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm writing this to learn and exercise, so C.B. solution fits my case better. However, this is very useful, too, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog, the simplest way to implement it is:

```
?- numlist(1, 5, List), sum_list(List, Sum).
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Sum = 15.
```

Your code tries to evaluate `C+A` but `C` is not known yet, therefore the error message.

Btw, you can also calculate this sum directly, without any iteration or list generation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/sum-of-n-consecutive-numbers

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use brute force to [compute the sum of a finite arithmetic sequence](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html), but wouldn't it be easier just to use your maths?

```
sum(A,B,X) :-
  A =< B ,
  N is 1+B-A ,
  X is N*(A+B) / 2
  .
```

Or, more generally, for computing the sum of a finite sequence of *n* terms, starting with *a*, with a "step size" (relative difference) of *d*, you get:

```
sum(A,D,N,S) :- S is (N*(2*A+(N-1)*D))/2 .
```

But if you're going to use brute force, make it tail recursive:

```
sum(A,B,S) :- A =< B , sum(A,B,0,S) .

sum(A,B,S,S) :-
  A > B
  .
sum(A,B,T,S) :-
  A =< B ,
  T1 is T+A ,
  A1 is A+1 ,
  sum(A1,B,T1,S)
  .
```